# Spring Data JPA Save method not working as expected with threadpool got exception

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa

I have a simple POJO entity class Passenger with a set of Addresses. The below is Passenger class and Address class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_pass")
public class Passenger implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "pid")
    private int pid;

    @Column(name = "pname")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "ploc")
    private int location;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "passenger", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<TripOrder> orders;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "passenger", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<MyAddress> myAddresses;


    @Override
    public Passenger clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Passenger clone = (Passenger) super.clone();
        return clone;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getPid() + " " + this.getName();
    }
}
```

The below is the MyAddress class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_add")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyAddress implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String City;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pid")
    private Passenger passenger;
}
```

The below is my Service layer, the save() method is just inherited from interface CrudRepository

```
@Transactional
@Async(value = "myTaskExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<Passenger> saveOne(Passenger passenger){
    Passenger save = passengerRepository.save(passenger);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(save);
}
```

and my threadpool:

```
@Configuration
public class ExecutorConfig {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor myTaskExecutor(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(40);
        taskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

}
```

I passed the below test method successfully:

```
    @Test
    public void test1() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        String[] name = new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
        String[] city = new String[]{"Alexander City", "Andalusia",  "Anniston","Athens", "Atmore", "Auburn","Bessemer", "Birmingham", "Chickasaw", "Clanton", "Cullman", "Decatur", "Demopolis", "Dothan", "Enterprise", "Eufaula", "Florence", "Fort Payne", "Gadsden", "Greenville", "Guntersville", "Huntsville", "Jasper", "Marion", "Mobile", "Montgomery"};
        Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
            Passenger p = passenger.clone();
            int nextInt = random.nextInt(26);
            p.setName(name[nextInt]);
            p.setLocation(nextInt);
            HashSet<MyAddress> set = new HashSet<>();
            MyAddress myAddress = new MyAddress();
            myAddress.setCity(city[nextInt]);
            myAddress.setPassenger(p);
            set.add(myAddress);
            p.setMyAddresses(set);
            p.getMyAddresses().add(myAddress);
            passengerService.saveOne(p);
        }
        List<Passenger> allPassengers = passengerService.findPassengers();
        Assertions.assertEquals(allPassengers.size(), 200);
        allPassengers.forEach(x -> Assertions.assertNotEquals(0, x.getMyAddresses().size()));
    }
```

But then I truncate my tables and change the loop from **200** to **2**

```
@Test
public void test1() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    String[] name = new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    String[] city = new String[]{"Alexander City", "Andalusia",  "Anniston","Athens", "Atmore", "Auburn","Bessemer", "Birmingham", "Chickasaw", "Clanton", "Cullman", "Decatur", "Demopolis", "Dothan", "Enterprise", "Eufaula", "Florence", "Fort Payne", "Gadsden", "Greenville", "Guntersville", "Huntsville", "Jasper", "Marion", "Mobile", "Montgomery"};
    Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        Passenger p = passenger.clone();
        int nextInt = random.nextInt(26);
        p.setName(name[nextInt]);
        p.setLocation(nextInt);
        HashSet<MyAddress> set = new HashSet<>();
        MyAddress myAddress = new MyAddress();
        myAddress.setCity(city[nextInt]);
        myAddress.setPassenger(p);
        set.add(myAddress);
        p.setMyAddresses(set);
        p.getMyAddresses().add(myAddress);
        passengerService.saveOne(p);
    }
    List<Passenger> allPassengers = passengerService.findPassengers();
    Assertions.assertEquals(allPassengers.size(), 2);
    allPassengers.forEach(x -> Assertions.assertNotEquals(0, x.getMyAddresses().size()));
}
```

I receive the below information:

```
    2022-01-01 18:04:56.028  INFO 12452 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-01-01 18:04:56.645  INFO 12452 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-01-01 18:04:56.745  INFO 12452 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2022-01-01 18:04:59.216  INFO 12452 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-01-01 18:04:59.231  INFO 12452 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-01-01 18:05:02.813  WARN 12452 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-01-01 18:05:04.350  INFO 12452 --- [           main] com.zjw.jpareview.PassengerTest          : Started PassengerTest in 14.188 seconds (JVM running for 17.218)
Hibernate: insert into tbl_pass (ploc, pname) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into tbl_pass (ploc, pname) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select passenger0_.pid as pid1_2_, passenger0_.ploc as ploc2_2_, passenger0_.pname as pname3_2_ from tbl_pass passenger0_
Hibernate: insert into tbl_add (city, pid) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into tbl_add (city, pid) values (?, ?)

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :0
Actual   :2
<Click to see difference>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:145)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:527)
    at com.zjw.jpareview.PassengerTest.test1(PassengerTest.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)    
2022-01-01 18:05:04.691  INFO 12452 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-01-01 18:05:04.691  INFO 12452 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-01-01 18:05:04.738  WARN 12452 --- [yTaskExecutor-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@15b49e1a marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 69 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 69 milliseconds ago.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1098) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1371) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1031) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:58) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:784) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:752) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:543) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:459) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) [hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:760) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:746) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:624) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:638) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.zjw.jpareview.service.PassengerService.saveOne(PassengerService.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.zjw.jpareview.service.PassengerService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7e1892a3.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.lambda$doSubmit$3(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:276) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 69 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 69 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:520) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:700) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:639) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:987) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:666) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:930) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Socket closed
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1563) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$400(SSLSocketImpl.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeaderLocal(SimplePacketReader.java:81) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:514) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    ... 101 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1341) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:957) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    ... 111 common frames omitted

2022-01-01 18:05:04.738  WARN 12452 --- [yTaskExecutor-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@43e37fbe marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)
```

I saw those SQL statements, which are expected, but why did they get rollbacked? and how come 200 works but 2 not working? Appreciate it if anyone can help me understand it.